# using UUID1 with phpcassa

Tags: cassandra, uuid, phpcassa

Have following CF:

```
create column family gr_ip2
with column_type = 'Standard' and comparator = 'TimeUUIDType(reversed=true)' ...;
```

then do following code:

```
$uuid1 = phpcassa\UUID::uuid1(null, $time);
$cf->insert("$key"  , array($uuid1 => $url) );
```

it works without exceptions, but CF at the end is empty.

Comment: What does the Cassandra log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$uuid1 is not string, but an object. When we do

```
$cf->insert("$key"  , array($uuid1 => $url) );
```

the object is converted to string, and insert fails. 
phpcassa does not give exeption, but insert fails anyway.

Seems like we need to use ARRAY_FORMAT, so the object not to be "flatten" to string,

```
$uuid1 = phpcassa\UUID::uuid1(null, $time);

$cf->insert_format = phpcassa\ColumnFamily::ARRAY_FORMAT;

$cf->insert("$key"  , array(
      array($uuid1, $url)
) );
```